# Effect of pipe length with fan

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, flow

I would like to know the effect that pipe length has on flow rate for a fan that I use in a system.

The fan horizontaly, draws ambient air up through a 6mm (int.dia) tube. As the length of the pipe increases I expect the flow rate to drop as the pressure increases as shown in the data sheet (attached).

My question is, how can I work out the flow rate for different lengths of tube, say 1m, 3m, 5m, 10m, when the pressure of the fan is not constant?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an indication : try to relate the pressure drop to the viscous friction of the flow at wall (you will have to compute the Reynolds number, and to wonder whether the flow is laminar or turbulent)